# is there a way to let github codespaces to connect my other SQL server?

Tags: portforwarding, codespaces, github-codespaces

is there a way to allow specified IP, which codespaces can connect?

i've tried to ping everything inside a codespace, and all got nothing, such as bing.com, github.com etc..